# Can I attach Multi Valued extras to CKAN resources?

Tags: ckan

Can I attach Multi Valued extras to CKAN resources (resource level meta data).

Data set level extras works well even with multi valued fields. So, It does'nt work with resource level. Is, it because the resource doesn't have resource_extra table, like package_extra.